# Java Gui L&F Round Button

Tags: java, user-interface

I am currently developing the front end of an app,using WindowsBuilder plugin on eclipse, in which i have a "toolbar" on the top of the frame
with different butttons a user can interact with. I want the buttons to be circles, with a custom icon that i will add.When "mouse enters" i want the hovered over button to enlarge and when "mouse exits" i want the button to go back to normal. The problems I have encountered so far are the following:

1. Cannot make circular button.
2. How to enlarge/reduce them(apart from set.width() + something , setHeight() + somethingElse

I want something like this:

[image: Poor drawing skills. My apologies]

I have already tried the jtattoo L&F for circle button but the 1.3 version throws error and the 1.6 does not throw one but does not change the button shape.

Note:The reason i ask these 2 questiong together is that they can be solved(i think) with a single L&F theme if someone has developed/knows one.

Comment: Starting out simple: you can use circular icons (http://69.89.12.71/java_swing_mustang_screenshots_gtk.html) including simply a larger rollover image and remove some button decorations like borders. If that's not sufficient, you might need to describe more your requirements which that doesn't meet: (e.g. More precise hit zone? Animation? Needs to actually expand over other controls...?)

Comment: As you correctly guessed it's like a middle ground solution. I do want the hit zone(if that does not take some serious time amount to implement),and even if i find a work around to that,when i add an icon to my buttons the icon takes an arbitrary(?) size. To clarify this,if i have an image i don't know how to make it fit the button's area. Regarding the animation, i would love it,but it's not a must. A simple enlargment would suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some time ago I wrote an [OvalButton](https://github.com/lukakralj/Snippets/blob/master/Java/ovalButton/OvalButton.java) class that can handle oval, circular and capsule-like shaped JButtons.

You can extend this class and override `getBackgroundImage()` method to return the image you want to set it as the background of the button. Then add listeners and text as usually. Only a click on the oval/circular area triggers the action.

When you get this ready I believe you should be able to import a new component.

Comment: So pretty much i just instantiate a new OvalButton instead of a JButton?

Comment: Yes. You only need to replace `new JButton()` with `new OvalButton()`. The button will be a circle as long as its height and width are the same. The rest should work because OvalButton inherits from JButton.

Comment: I just played around with your class. Very good job. Needs very little modification to fit perfectly. If you get back to developing it, imo, add nested enums and it's perfect. well done!